# Using dlm and dsd correctly

Tags: sas, dlm

In my text file, the data is seperated by `|`. So I used the code

```
data TEST.something;
infile something dlm = '|' dsd missover firstobs=2;
  input Proc_cde : $3.
  Profession_Name : $16.
  Lic_id : $8.
  Expire_Date : mmddyy10.
  Original_Date : mmddyy10.
  Rank_Code : $2.
  License_Number : $5.
  Status_Effective_Date:  mmddyy10.
  Board_action_Indicator : $1.
  License_Status_Description : $5.

  Last_name : $20.
  First_Name : $14.
  License_Active_Description : $8.
  e_mail $30.
  ;
```

But in my text file, I have missing values such as `ETIEXXX|MILTHYYY||||ACTIVE|23`

When I print out the data, some of the values I wanted are not showed but others are correct. It also shows `||` in some place. The data were shifted.

So what is wrong?

**EDIT**

Sample data (only list a few lines).

```
pro_cde|Profession-Name|lic_id|Expire-Date|Original-Date|Rank-Code|License-Number|Status-Effective-Date|Board-Action-Indicator|License-Status-Description|Last-Name|First-Name|Middle-Name|Name-Suffix|Business-Name|License-Active-Status-Description|County|County-Description|Mailing-Address-Line1|Mailing-Address-line2|Mailing-Address-City|Mailing-Address-State|Mailing-Address-ZIPcode|Mailing-Address-Area-Code|Mailing-Address-Phone-Number|Mailing-Address-Phone-Extension|Practice-Location-Address-Line1|Practice-Location-Address-line2|Practice-Location-Address-City|Practice-Location-Address-State|Practice-Location-Address-ZIPcode|Email|Mod-Cdes|Prescribe-Ind|Dispensing-Ind|
 732|Dental Hygienist|@2783168|03/28/2016|08/01/2005|SC|16042|08/01/2002|N|CLEAR|ETIEXXX|MILTHYYY||||ACTIVE|23|UIARI-DADE| P.O BOX 692343||MIAMI|FL|34568|815|738-4640||13830 S.W 6TH AVE||UIARI|NY|34568|emi3th4ne@yahoo.com||||
 732|Dental Hygienist|690|03/28/2016||CA|1143|04/20/2013|N|CLEAR|WTGD|CUIOLYN|J|||ACTIVE|56|OKALOOSA|5702 OLD BETHEL RD||CRESTVIEW|FL|32536|850|862-0924||90 RATETRACK ROAD||FORT WCLTON BEACH|VA|32547|||||
 732|Dental Hygienist|9728|03/28/2016|08/27/1998|SD|11119|03/15/2012|N|CLEAR|RTED|RIHGARD|B|||ACTIVE|39|HILLSBOROUGH|249 APACHE TRAIL||BRANDON|ND|34568|313|659-7798||249 APDDHE TRAIL||BRANDON|FL|34568|||||
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have there, so you'll have to show some example data that actually fails (and makes sense with your input statement - your example there doesn't).

Comment: Your probably using the colon and formats incorrectly but as Joe indicated, without the data we can't comment beyond this. DSD is required to interpret consecutive delimiters as missing values.

Comment: @Joe , sample data is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of variables on your INPUT statement does not match your list of variables in the first line of your data. You skipped a lot columns.

You can skip columns if you want by adding some dummy variables into your INPUT statement.  You must add the `:` modifier in front of any informats you specify in your INPUT statement to prevent SAS from reading past the delimiters.

```
length dummy $1 ;
drop dummy ;
input
  Proc_cde : $3.
  ...
  First_Name : $14.
  3*dummy
  License_Active_Description : $8.
  15*dummy
  e_mail :$30.
;
```

Comment: I only want to print the selected columns. Do I need to put all variables in the INPUT statement?

Comment: Printing or taking the means or running a regression has nothing to do with telling SAS how to read your text file into a dataset.  If you only want to print some of the variables use the VAR statement in the PROC PRINT step.

Comment: So do you suggest to use `DSD`and `dlm`?

Comment: Yes. You need to use DLM to tell SAS that the data is delimited with |. You need to use DSD to tell SAS that adjacent || indicate that a value was null.

Comment: My code: `input Proc_cde : $3.
      Profession_Name : $16.
      Lic_id : $8.
      Expire_Date : mmddyy10.
      Original_Date : mmddyy10.
      Rank_Code : $2.
      License_Number : $5.
      Status_Effective_Date:  mmddyy10.
      Board_action_Indicator : $1.
      License_Status_Description : $5.
      Last_name : $20.
      First_Name : $14. 
      3*dummy
      License_Active_Description : $8.
      15*dummy
      e_mail $40.
      3*dummy
      ;`. I checked the date set. It lists from Proc_code to e_mail.The email column is wrong. Empty or including next column.

Comment: If you are specifying informats on your INPUT statement when reading from a delimited file (which is a bad idea) then you need to use the : modifier to prevent SAS from reading past the delimiters. You do not have one for the EMAIL field.